# Can you tell if a book on Amazon is print-on-demand?

Tags: publishing

For context: I have a poetry chapbook which has been published by a small publisher. The book is sold through their website and through Amazon. Unfortunately, my publisher is not very communicative and I have several friends who ordered my book from them and haven't received it. I'm wondering if the book is print-on-demand (which means folks can pretty reliably order it from Amazon) or if the publisher is supplying Amazon with copies (which means it is unreliable).

Is there a way to figure out if a book is print-on-demand or not when sold on Amazon?

Comment: I imagine you signed a contract with the publisher, this may be stated in the contract, e.g. 'the service provided is print-on-demand' or 'the publisher agrees to print a minimum of 500 copies'

Comment: @NofP nothing is said specifically, but it sounds like they printed and have stock.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the book? Does it say something at the start on the copyright page or around there, or at the end? Many books will say where they were printed as well as listing the publisher.

Answer (score -1):

If it is paperback from amazon, then You can get it made.

My books are paperback and kindle, and I can get them printed on demand.

I am a self-publisher (JesperSB on Amazon), so it might be different from You.

Unless the contract says so, You could also just put it up, as a self publish.

Comment: This book is not self-published. There is a publisher. They are just mostly useless. I have a contract. So I'm not talking about me re-publishing it. I know how to do that. I'm trying to figure out if the existing book is sold through Amazon via inventory or print-on-demand.